# How can i test to see if the row is even in a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to test each row in my array to see if they are even or odd. If the row is even i want to change the random value in the elements of the row to 0. If the row is odd i want to change the elements to 1. Ive been able to create the element and print it out but im stuck on how to test the rows. I know to test if a number is even you use (i % 2 == 0) but im not sure what coding i should use.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] box;
    box = new int[2][2];

    int row;
    int column;

    for (row = 0; row < box.length; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < box[row].length; column++) {
            box[row][column] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        }
    }
   //where im having issues
    // i get error 'bad operand types for binary operator'

     if (box[row] % 2 == 0) {
        for (row = 0; row< box.length;row++){
           box[row][column] = [0][];
        }
     }
    else{
        for(row = 0; row < box.length; row++){
            box[row][column] = [1][];
        }
    }      

    for (row = 0; row < box.length; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < box[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(box[row][column] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the sum of the row should be even, or every single element?

Comment: What is the type of `box[row]` and how do you expect to test whether or not *that* is even? If you want to test whether the *row number* is even, that's just a matter of using `row % 2`... although you should note that you're using `row` and `column` outside any loop, so they won't have useful values. (I would suggest you remove the current declarations of `row` and `column`, and declare them as part of each `for` loop instead.)

Comment: I want to test the index and see if its even.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Arrays` built in function `fill(int[],value)` that takes two argument, First 1d array and second a value to fill

```
//also if you are checking is row is even or odd divide row not box[row]
if (row % 2 == 0) {
        Arrays.fill(box[row],0);//set 0 to every element in this wor
}
else{  
        Arrays.fill(box[row],1);//set 1 to every element in this wor        
}
```

Comment: I tried this i get the error ' non static variable row cannot be references from a static context'

Comment: can you explain what you want to accomplish , your question is bit unclear and also you are using value row in your condition whose value is 2 by the first for loop